# Invisible / transparent button that works like a regular in android?

Tags: android, image, button, invisible

How do I get one area in the middle of a image clickable (not the whole image)? Tried with a button set to invisible and clickable but the button does not work. What are the alternatives to an invisible / transparent button that works like a regular?

I've also thought of a completely transparent and clickable PNG that should work but maybe not the best way?

Answer (score 29):

Here you go:

```
Button theButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.theButton);
theButton.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
theButton.setBackgroundColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);

phoneButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener()
{   
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
        // DO STUFF
    }
});
```

Comment: Also, using XML layout attribute: `android:background="@android:color/transparent"`.

Comment: one thing you might also need (for like an invisible easter egg button) is `theButton.setTextColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);`

Answer (score 22):

```
android:background="@android:color/transparent"
```

Answer (score 6):

You can try set transparent background to the button. But do not change buttons visibility, cause that prevents view from getting click events.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
android:background = "@null"
```

Answer (score 0):

There's:

```
android:background="?android:attr/selectableItemBackground"
```