# how to give onclick to Animation?

Tags: android, android-animation

In my project I am using different animations in a single xml file, like Fruit Ninja game. When I click on the particular image, that image should be invisible and out count will be increase by 100, for this list I want to know how to give on click to moving image i.e., animated image.

```
 LinearLayout r=new LinearLayout(this);
 i1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
 i2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
 i3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView3);
 i4 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView4);
 i5 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView5);
 i6 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView6);
 i7 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView7);
 i8 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView8);
 i9 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView9);
 i10 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.imageView10);

 final Animation an=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.custom);
 final Animation an1=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.custom1);
 final Animation an2=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.custom2);
 final Animation an3=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.custom3);
 final Animation an4=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.custom4);
 final Animation an5=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.custom5);
 final Animation an6=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.custom6);
 final Animation an7=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.custom7);
 final Animation an8=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.custom8);
 final Animation an9=AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this,R.anim.custom9);
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried this

```
ImageView myImage = (ImageView) findViewById(R.idimageView1);
```

Then, set Visibility to GONE

```
myImage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

also [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3775726/invisible-transparent-button-that-works-like-a-regular-in-android)